# How I can export the history of my commands in Windows(7) Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I know I can use arrow keys, but I need to see a full list of history and perhaps export it to a txt file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> you can browse the history of commands.

To store it as a plain text file, use this command (which will be included too):

```
DOSKEY /HISTORY >filename
```

Source:

- [Saving windows command prompt history to a file](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2011/1/27/Saving_windows_command_prompt_history_to_file)